# Convert SQL Server T-SQL wide result to readable text format

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008, xslt

I have the following T-SQL (SQL Server 2008) and I need to email the result using database mail.

```
select top 5 col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6
from aTable
order by colOrder desc
```

col1 to col6 are long nvarchar(4000) and result is not readable. I wish the result be shown as

```
col1: aaa asa 11 11111111111111111111111111111111111111
col2: 22222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222
col3: 333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333
col4: 44444444444444444
col5: 555555555555555555555
col6: 666666666666

col1: bbbbbbb 1111111111111111111111111111111111
col2: 22 222 222222222222222222222
....
```

Is it possible to use `for xml` with xlst to transform the result?

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look a the COALESCE function to pivot you resultset :

Here is an example for your query :

```
DECLARE 
    @col1 nvarchar(max),
    @col2 nvarchar(max)


SELECT top 5 
    @col1 = COALESCE(@col1,'') + col1 + ' '
    ,@col2 = COALESCE(@col2,'') + col2 + ' '
FROM aTable
ORDER BY colOrder

SELECT 'Col1: ' + @col1
union
SELECT 'Col2: ' + @col2
```

Source :http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1521/the-many-uses-of-coalesce-in-sql-server/